# Read file with kernel32.dll (Python)

Tags: python, kernel32

I need to read file using kernel32.dll. I have read about CreateFile, SetFilePointer and ReadFile methods (I need to use them) - but not sure how to apply them.

As mentioned [at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  I need to specify all those arguments. I know that first is path to file, but have no idea what are those other arguments and in what way should I insert them.

Can anyone help me with "howto" on kernel32.dll CreateFile, SetFilePointer and ReadFile.

Really appreciate any help.

**Update**

The reason I try to use kernel32 is that I need really-really fast way to read from flash-drive. I need some way that will read directly from flash, without spending time in its file system. By this I mean direct access to required byte, without some long searches in file system.

Here is code I used for reading

```
    index = 524288
    data = open('Path-to-file', 'rb')
    while index < file_length:
        data.seek(index)
        headers.append((index, data.read(128)))
        index += cluster
    data.close()
```

This code takes about 8 minutes to look through 1 Gb file via USB.

I need it to be done at 4 minutes.

If someone has any suggestions how I can do it other way - I would really appreciate.

**Update**

I have tried win32file (pywin32) like this:

```
def get_headers(self):
    while self.index < self.file_len:
        handle = win32file.CreateFile(self.path, win32file.GENERIC_READ,
                                      win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ, None,
                                      win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
        win32file.SetFilePointer(handle, self.index, win32file.FILE_CURRENT)
        header_ = win32file.ReadFile(handle, 128, None)
        header = header_[1]
        self.headers.append((self.index, header))
        self.index += cluster
        win32file.CloseHandle(handle)
```

It takes more time (12 minutes) than python "seek" and "read" functions.
Does anyone know why usage of module for Windows dll increases time of reading?

Comment: Do you think flash drives DON'T use a file system?

Comment: Are you trying to access raw bytes on the drive or seek to a position in a file (if raw then I'm not sure either high level interface will help). If within a file then stick with the python code. The underlying file access is probably C based and about as fast as you are going to get without going to a lower level language. Also what is the filesystem on your thumb drive?

Comment: Filesystem is FAT32. Here is what I am trying to do: I have binary file with raw bytes. I need to seek at start of each cluster, read header and save it. Does it worth a shot to try write **reading** in C?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most common use of `CreateFile`:

```
hFile = CreateFile("file.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, 3, 128, None)
```

And `ReadFile`:

```
ReadFile(hFile, pOutput, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, 0)
```

Note that, if you use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), you'll need `c_char_p` (which represents a string) for `pOutput` (where the file content will be stored), and `byref`or `pointer` for `lpNumberOfBytesRead`.

You can also use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) which I'm sure will be simpler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How should I specify `CreateFile` function? I tried this, but it does not work: `kernel = ctypes.windll.kernel32`;                            `handle = kernel.CreateFileW(self.path, kernel.GENERIC_READ,
kernel.FILE_SHARE_READ, None, kernel.OPEN_EXISTING,
kernel.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None) `

Comment: That should work. If yo're using `CreateFileW`, be sure `self.path` is a unicode string. You can also use `GetLastError` to see what's happening.

Comment: First of all, I got error that `GENERIC_READ` is not found for kernel. So I just cant use it like this

Comment: Just define it: `GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000`.